# SignalR core JWT claims

Tags: authentication, jwt, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

```
cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived = context =>
                        {
                            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                            // If the request is for our hub...
                            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                                (path.StartsWithSegments("/sas")))
                            {
                                // Read the token out of the query string
                                context.Token = accessToken;
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
```

In my hub, I tried to get claims like that:

```
Context.User.Claims
```

but they're empty.

Is there any option to get my JWT claims in my signalr hub?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I've solved it by replacing this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

with this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```

For some reason, I had to explicitly define the `DefaultAuthenticateScheme`. I still don't know why the `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` didn't fallback automatically to the `DefaultScheme` as it should according to the documentation. If I find out the reason, I'll update the answer.